# Using a method's return as another object's property name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm running an SQL query that is replacing my template's placeholders with values depending on the user's language settings. If he e.g. selected "en_us", then my php should select the "en_us" column from the replacements table. For now I tried s.th. like:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    $html = str_replace("{" . $row->origin . "}", $row->$user->getLanguage(), $html);
}
```

but it won't work. Does anyone has any idea how to achieve this?
The method `$user->getLanguage()` gives back a string containing "en_us".

**My HTML (just a template file):**

```
<head>

    <meta charset="{CHARSET}" />

    <base href="{BASE}" />
    <meta name="version" conent="{VERSION}" />

    <title>{TITLE}{TITLE_STD}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="{DESCRIPTION}" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="{KEYWORDS}" />

    <meta name="author" content="{AUTHOR}" />

    <link rel="favicon" href="{FAVICON}" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#2d2d2d" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Roboto|Montserrat" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/desk/core.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/desk/header.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/desk/aside.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/desk/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/desk/popups.css" />

    <script src="/js/jQuery/min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/include.js"></script>
```

**And my error message is:**
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class User could not be converted to string in ... on line ...

Comment: can you add a little more context?  what did the `$html` var look like before and after your attempt?

Comment: "I'm running an SQL query"...yet you seem to be operating on a variable called `$html`...this suggests you're too late in the process. If you want to select from a particular column in the database, you need to modify the SQL query, not the HTML result.

Comment: This is a replacement within my SQL query while loop. If I write a static en_us instead of $user->getLanguage() it works,but I want it to be variable without dozens of if's.

Comment: What's in `$row->user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to force PHP to dereference `$user->getLanguage()` first, and then use that value when dereferencing `$row`. You can do this simply by using braces as you would parens in a mathematical expression:

```
$row->{$user->getLanguage()}
```

Comment: This is what I searched fo, tried it with these ones "()" first, but it didn't work.. Thanks

Comment: Please work on your accept ratio, you will experience difficulty getting answers in the future if all your questions are unaccepted.